# tfjs nodejs: util_1.promisify is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow

In a Meteor app I try to use Tensorflow. 
package.json:

```
"@tensorflow/tfjs": "^0.14.0",
"@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^0.1.21",
```

Then import:

```
import '@tensorflow/tfjs-node';
```

Then nothing else. The code is included just to provide functionality to `face-api.js`. When import is uncommented, page is not loaded in browser, and `util_1.promisify is not a function` happens in module.js:

[image]